# Keras: best model from keras_tuner has a different mse when evaluated

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, hyperparameters

I'm trying to 1) tune my hyperparameters and 2) save the best model. But I noticed that the mse from the 'best model' is different from what the keras_tuner output said it would be. My code and output are below:

```
tuner = RandomSearch(
  hypermodel =  build_model,
  max_trials = 5,
  executions_per_trial = 5,
  hyperparameters = hp,
  tune_new_entries = T,
  objective = 'mse',
  project_name = project_name, 
  overwrite = TRUE
)

tuner %>% fit_tuner(x = x, y = y, 
                    epochs = 100, 
                    validation_data = list(x_val, y_val))

best_model <- tuner %>% get_best_models(1)

tuner %>% results_summary(1)

best_model[[1]] %>% evaluate(x=x, y=y)
```

and output (from the last two lines is):

```
# Output from tuner %>% results_summary(1):

Showing 1 best trials
<keras_tuner.engine.objective.Objective object at 0x0000026FAE07C610>
Trial summary
Hyperparameters:
num_layers: 3
units: 30
Score: 0.23338192105293273

# Output from best_model[[1]] %>% evaluate(x=x, y=y):

32/32 [==============================] - 0s 676us/step - loss: 0.1719 - mse: 0.1719
     loss       mse 
0.1718763 0.1718763
```

The **Score** from `results_summary` is different from the **mse** from evaluating the best model. What am I missing here? I think they should be the same.

EDIT:

The data are produced with

```
  a = rnorm(1000)
  b = rnorm(1000)
  c = rnorm(1000)
  
  y = matrix(c(a,b,c), nrow = 1000)
  
  x = lapply(1:20, function(i) y[,1]*i^2 + y[,2]*i + y[,3]) %>% unlist() %>% matrix(nrow = 1000)
```

and `x_val` and `y_val` are defined analgously

Comment: Your code is incomplete. One or more lines are missing at the start.

Comment: Sorry, edited. just ```tuner = RandomSearch(``` was missing

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: edited to include how the data is generated, but the data shouldn't really matter. I'm just confused about why the tuner says that the mse of the best model is 0.2333, but when I extract the best model and fit it to the same data the mse is 0.1719?